# Changing color of a <td> in a static HTML Table, depending if the BackEnd data is true or not in AngularJS without ng-Repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-table

**Warning: some words are in french in my code on pictures so I will explain what is about here**

[This is table I am trying to change the color depending on the true of false value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBU4F.jpg)

It is a simple disponibility schedule for each employees for the periods of AM,PM and Noon of a Day.

At this moment all I am trying to do is to displayed the values of, if someone is available at that period of this day,the the  will turn turn green. In my database, each period displayed here are in bit values.

I will use the combo-box to switch employees(right now it display their ID but it only temporary )

The problem is, I can't get to display them properly, the values are incorrect !  So I am gonna post a paste bin of my code for this part right here.

```
 <!-- The view code-->

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top:10px;">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <b>Horraires des disponibilités </b>
            </div>


            <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <div >
                        <label>  Employer  </label>
                        <select ng-model="emp.EmployerID"  ng-change="SelectedEmployer(emp.EmployerID)"    class="form-control">
                            <option  ng-repeat="emp in LesDisponibilites" >{{emp.EmployerID}}</option>

                        </select>

                    </div>
               </div><div class="col-lg-6"><div class="dataTables_filter"><label><b>Search:</b><input type="search" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="dataTables-example"></label></div></div>


                <!-- /.panel-heading -->

                <div class="col-lg-10 ">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table  class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                            <thead  >
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Jour</th>
                                    <th>AM</th>
                                    <th>PM</th>
                                    <th>Soir</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody >
                                <tr  >
                                    <td>Lundi</td>
                                    <td  ng-required="IsDispo(LesDisponibilites[Lindex].Lundi_AM)" style="background-color:{{DispoColor}};"></td>
                                    <td ng-required="IsDispo(LesDisponibilites[Lindex].Lundi_PM)" style="background-color:{{DispoColor}};"></td>
                                    <td ng-required="IsDispo(LesDisponibilites[Lindex].Lundi_Soir)" style="background-color:{{DispoColor}};"></td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Mardi</td>
                                    <td ng-required="IsDispo(LesDisponibilites[Lindex].Mardi_AM)" style="background-color:{{DispoColor}};"></td>
                                    <td ng-required="IsDispo(LesDisponibilites[Lindex].Mardi_PM)" style="background-color:{{DispoColor}};"></td>
                                    <td ng-required="IsDispo(LesDisponibilites[Lindex].Mardi_Soir)" style="background-color:{{DispoColor}};"></td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Mercredi</td>
                                    <td ng-required="IsDispo(LesDisponibilites[Lindex].Mercredi_AM)" style="background-color:{{DispoColor}};"></td>
                                    <td ng-required="IsDispo(LesDisponibilites[Lindex].Mercredi_PM)" style="background-color:{{DispoColor}};"></td>
                                    <td ng-required="IsDispo(LesDisponibilites[Lindex].Mercredi_Soir)" style="background-color:{{DispoColor}};"></td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Jeudi</td>
                                    <td ng-required="IsDispo(LesDisponibilites[Lindex].Jeudi_AM)" style="background-color:{{DispoColor}};"></td>
                                    <td ng-required="IsDispo(LesDisponibilites[Lindex].Jeudi_PM)" style="background-color:{{DispoColor}};"></td>
                                    <td ng-required="IsDispo(LesDisponibilites[Lindex].Jeudi_Soir)" style="background-color:{{DispoColor}};"></td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Vendredi</td>
                                    <td ng-required="IsDispo(LesDisponibilites[Lindex].Vendredi_AM)" style="background-color:{{DispoColor}};"></td>
                                    <td ng-required="IsDispo(LesDisponibilites[Lindex].Vendredi_PM)" style="background-color:{{DispoColor}};"></td>
                                    <td ng-required="IsDispo(LesDisponibilites[Lindex].Vendredi_Soir)" style="background-color:{{DispoColor}};"></td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Samedi</td>
                                    <td ng-required="IsDispo(LesDisponibilites[Lindex].Samedi_AM)" style="background-color:{{DispoColor}};"></td>
                                    <td ng-required="IsDispo(LesDisponibilites[Lindex].Samedi_PM)" style="background-color:{{DispoColor}};"></td>
                                    <td ng-required="IsDispo(LesDisponibilites[Lindex].Samedi_Soir)" style="background-color:{{DispoColor}};"></td >

                                </tr>


                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                    </div>
                    <!-- /.table-responsive -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>




    // Controller code
    myappCtrl.controller('DisponibiliteCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    var url = "http://localhost:64124/api/disponibilites"

    $scope.DispoColor = "none";
    $scope.LesDisponibilites = {};
    $scope.Lindex = {};

    // Récupère le date 
    $http.get(url).then(function (result) {
        $scope.LesDisponibilites = result.data;
    })

    $scope.SelectedEmployer = function (index) {

        console.log(index);
        $scope.Lindex = index -1;

    }

    //  Pour ajouter les couleurs qui indiques les disponibilités 
    $scope.IsDispo = function (Dispo ) {



        if (Dispo == true) {
            $scope.DispoColor = "#0ac20a";
        }
        else {
            $scope.DispoColor = "none";
        }


    }
```

Also this is weird, but when I switch to ng-model instead of ng-required, It seems to show the correct data, but the console is going crazy with error, as ng-model should not be use for a Function.

I tried a lot of things and I am lost right now. I hope somebody here can help me.

Comment: Have you had a look at `ng-if` or `ng-class`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) or [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to doing that.

ng-style="expression" or ng-class="expression"

In your case, as an example you can apply following way for your rows.

```
 <td  ng-style="LesDisponibilites[Lindex].Lundi_AM ? {'background-color':'#0ac20a'}:'none' ></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try use ng-class property.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-condensed">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="col-xs-4">COLUMN1</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">COLUMN2</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">COLUMN3</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="obj in anyObject" ng-class="{'info': obj.value1}">
        <td class="col-xs-2">{{obj.value1}}</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">{{obj.value2}}</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">{{obj.value3}}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```